# Apache not starting in XAMPP in windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

On clicking the start button a windows dialog box pops up -:
[the dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPl50.jpg)

then the control panel is like this-:
[image of control pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BghT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the port 80 to 9000 or 81 or whatever you want in file httpd. conf on the line Listen 80. Change the port on httpd-ssl. conf and change Listen 443 to Listen 441.

Comment: Nothing happened, the problem remains the same

Comment: Changing the port has no effect, because binding to any port (does not matter if it is a well-known port or not) needs admin privileges, so UAC should pop up regardless of the configured port(s).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the question here exactly, but let's assume you are asking why this popup appears:

When you click "Start", then XAMPP will try to start Apache, a webserver. As can bee seen from the prompt, the command is basically `net start Apache2.4` which will try to start a service. However, starting a service needs administrative privileges on Windows (at least for default configurations). That is why there is such a popup for User Account Control (UAC). Furthermore, the server needs to bind to one or more [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)), e.g. port 80, 443 or similar ports. Binding to a port also needs administrative privileges on Windows (at least for default configuration). That is another reaseon why there would be such an elevation request from UAC.

**TL;DR:** Starting a Windows service needs admin powers, therefore UAC pops up.